# What HTTP status code should I use for processing status update?

Tags: http, https, postman, http-status-codes, status

I am building an application that sends a set of images to a custom server for processing. The processing can take up to several minutes, so I am implementing a progress bar in the app. The progress bar is updated via an http get request that returns a JSON object containing either an error message, the status of the processing, or the results of the processing.

Upon a successful upload (via put request) the server responds with a status of 202 Accepted.

The HTTP request responds with a status of 500 Internal Server Error if an error has occurred, 102 Processing if the processing has not completed, and 200 Ok if the processing is done and the results are available.

When I am testing in postman the content of the message when a 102 Processing status is returned is hidden, leading me to believe I am misunderstanding something about which codes I should be using. Do the HTTP codes I am using in these scenarios make sense or should I be using other codes?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`102 Processing` is not a "normal" status code. Like the others in the 100 series, they act more like an 'intermediate' status code.

When a server sends `102` or `10x`, it means that the client will continue to wait for a 'real' status code. So an actual single HTTP request might result in *all* of the following HTTP status codes:

- `100`
- `102`
- `102` (might appear more than once)
- `103`
- `103`
- `200` (finally got the real 'OK').

Your use-case is *not* an appropiate usage of `102`, unless you keep the connection open and send more status-codes. Many HTTP clients don't have a built-in way to notify you of these 'intermediate statuses', but some do.

Given that you're doing a sort of polling and you have a resource that represents 'the status of the image' (I'm imagining something like `/image/{upload-id}/status` it's fine for that resource to return `200 OK` both when the image has and has not been processed.

Think about it this way, regardless of the image itself, the 'status of the image'-resource is always available and can return 200.

Plug: I wrote a [blog post](https://evertpot.com/http/102-processing) about this code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about the 102 status. Is it not appropriate to use the status code to tell if the processing is complete or not? Is it better to encode this in the response body?

Comment: Basically what you want to do is create a resource that represents the 'status' of the image. The 'status' (whether it's processing or completed) always 'exists', so it should always be `200 OK`, further details can then go in the body. Hope that explains it!